# "Package not found in repositories" error from OpenWrap

Tags: openwrap

I downloaded and installed OpenWrap, since allegedly it was the best way to get binaries for OpenRasta. But when I try to run `o add-wrap openrasta-full`, OpenWrap gives me this error:

> Package openrasta-full not found in repositories.

Just to cover my bases, I also tried `o add-wrap openrasta-devtools`, since that's the command that's specifically given as an example on the [OpenWrap homepage](http://www.openwrap.org/). It just gave me the same error (with the different package name, of course).

When I installed OpenWrap (o.exe) from openwrap.org, and ran it the first time, I got a console window asking if I wanted to install, and I chose the "install and add to the path" option. It chugged for several minutes, downloading packages, but then the console window closed, so I don't know if the "install" completed successfully. Now when I try to re-run the file I downloaded, I just get an error: "The term 'o' is not a recognized command or alias. Check the spelling or enter 'get-help' to get a list of available commands." So apparently it's the same EXE and self-installs, so I have no way to re-run the install or even tell whether it was successful.

How can I troubleshoot this and get OpenRasta installed?

Comment: We've had some server problems around the time you asked your question it may have been it. I'll double-check things tomorrow and answer properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was some issues with the 2.1 packages that all should have been resolved now.

To create an OpenRasta site you can:

## OpenWrap 1.0

With 1.0, you need to first create a new project

```
c:\src> o init-wrap myProject
c:\src> cd myProject
```

Then create a new asp.net site (or console app or whatever you want). You then need to hook up OpenWrap to your project.

```
c:\src\myProject> o init-wrap -all
```

And finally add the OpenRasta packages to your project.

```
c:\src\myProject> o add-wrap openrasta-full
```

## OpenWrap 2.0

If you're using OpenWrap 2.0, it's a bit easier.

First, install the devtools on your system.

```
c:\src> o add-wrap openrasta-devtools -system
```

Then initialize a new project

```
c:\src> o init-wrap myProject
c:\src> cd myProject
```

And create a new OpenRasta site using

```
c:\src\myProject> o new-OpenRastaSite mySolutionName My.Base.Namespace
```

This will use the default templates to create an OpenRasta site.

As OpenWrap 2.0 gets more functionality around templating, I'll probably make the openwrap creation implicit (if you're not within an OpenWrap project, the templates will create one) and more options available in the template (hosting type for example).